# saving an array in a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have an array in VB with numbers. 
How can I save this in a txt file?

In R, for example, I do it like this: "write.matrix(A,file=name)". 
So the array with "name" is also stored in VB and I want to do the same thing here.

regards,
daniel

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I am searching for a good way to do this. In R/MatLab it is so easy, so I hope VB can do it similarly.

Comment: Did you even search for "VB.NET write file"?

Comment: I had a look at several sites/blogs.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it to a csv file, f.e. pipe delimited (because numbers can contain commas):

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, String.Join("|", numbers))
```

[`File.WriteAllText` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)

You can load the array later in this way:

```
Dim split = From str In File.ReadAllText(filePath).Split("|"c)
            Select Double.Parse(str)
Dim numbers As Double() = split.ToArray()
```